# How to setup Munin permissions?

Tags: permissions, centos, munin

I've just installed munin on my CentOS server but I can't get it to output anything to the html directory I set in /etc/munin/munin.conf
    htmldir /home/mydir/munin

In /var/log/munin/munin-graph.log I get errors like:
    2011/09/23 12:35:30 [RRD ERROR] Unable to graph /home/mydir/munin/localhost/localhost/memory-year.png : Opening '/home/mydir/munin/localhost/localhost/memory-year.png' for write: Permission denied

permissions on /home/mydir/munin are:
    drwxrwxr-x 2 munin        munin  4096 Sep 23 12:31 munin

Comment: So I managed to work around this by moving the htmldir to /var/www/munin where it's able to be written to and pointing apache conf to there.

Answer (score -1):

Also you need to check is SELinux running. Maybe SELinux ic blocking this writes.